# Using counter with For Loop

Tags: vb.net

I have a question about using a for loop.  Below is code for database filtering using visual basic 2008.

```
Private Sub txtsearch_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtsearch.KeyDown
    On Error Resume Next
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        ''  Me.Table1BindingSource.Filter = "EmpID = ' " & Me.txtsearch.Text & "'"
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim temp As Integer = 0
        Dim trytime As Integer = 0

        Me.Table1BindingSource.Filter = "EmpID = ' " & Me.txtsearch.Text & "'"

        For i As Integer = 0 To Table1DataGridView.RowCount - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To Table1DataGridView.ColumnCount - 1

                If Table1DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString = txtsearch.Text Then
                    ''if item found then we play sound ok
                    My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\beep.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
                    My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\beep.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)

                    temp = 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
        If temp = 0 Then

            ''if item not found then we play sound err
            My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\computer_access.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
            Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.MydbDataSet.Table1)
            Me.Table1DataGridView.Refresh()
            txtsearch.Text = ""

        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

my problem is when the search is not found for three times so display some **MSGBOX**

so where to put the **trytime** loop ?

Comment: What do you mean by *three times*? Will this procedure be called 3 times and then you want to display message? if yes, then the variable scope is wrongly defined. It should be outside of this procedure and you should increment it's value from this procedure.

Comment: i mean if the user try three time to enter wrong number then **MSGBOX** appears to tell him he had try 3 times ,, and be carful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: check the comments

```
Public Class Form1

    'Define the variable within the class scope
    Dim trytime As Integer = 0

    Private Sub txtsearch_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtsearch.KeyDown
        On Error Resume Next
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            ''  Me.Table1BindingSource.Filter = "EmpID = ' " & Me.txtsearch.Text & "'"
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim temp As Integer = 0

            Me.Table1BindingSource.Filter = "EmpID = ' " & Me.txtsearch.Text & "'"

            For i As Integer = 0 To Table1DataGridView.RowCount - 1
                For j As Integer = 0 To Table1DataGridView.ColumnCount - 1

                    If Table1DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString = txtsearch.Text Then
                        ''if item found then we play sound ok
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\beep.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\beep.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)

                        temp = 1


                    End If
                Next
            Next

            If temp = 0 Then 
                trytime += 1 'Increment if not found

                If trytime >= 3 then 'Check if not found 3 times (or more)
                  'Take action when not found 3 times
                End If

                ''if item not found then we play sound err
                My.Computer.Audio.Play("F:\computer_access.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
                Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.MydbDataSet.Table1)
                Me.Table1DataGridView.Refresh()
                txtsearch.Text = ""

            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: its works thanx , but with one small error 
`trytime += 1 'Increment if not found` must be before the second `if`

Comment: Right, my mistake :)

Comment: Actually it should be outside FOR loop to avoid over incrementing the value.

Comment: thanx due , Accepted

Comment: yup outside the first **FOR LOOP** , i 've edit it , ^_^